# How do I design a circuit for a bi-color led to display power?

Tags: led

I'm trying to create a simple circuit that will turn a [Red/Green LED](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/WP59EGW/754-1232-ND/1747631) green when the power is on and red when it is off. I figure the simplest way to do this would be using a SPDT switch, but the switch in the circuit I'm designing is a 40 amp relay, and I found a SPST one for about a buck while the SPDT one was almost 4. For future reference, and also to cut the cost of designing my current circuit I'm trying to come up with some way to wire it up and basically make a "normally on" switch for the red and "normally off for the green.

The closest I've come is finding this circuit which would work except for the fact that the bicolor led shares a cathode.

[image]

Is there any way to change up the circuit, or is there something else I can try which would free up the cathode to make it so I can independently switch on the two LEDs?

Comment: When the power is OFF, how do you power-up the RED Color LED?

Comment: This circuit would be used to power up the red LED when the switch is open, then the green LED would simply be wired up to the switch. Problem is I'd need two seperate LEDs for this particular circuit to work, and what I have is a bi-color with a common cathode.

Comment: Can you share the part number of LED you have

Comment: Added link to the LED I'm using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resistor, R4, is used to pulldown VLOAD when  the SPST switch, SW1, is open. This means that when SW1 is closed, VLOAD is high, and when SW1 is open, VLOAD is low.

An [NPN digital logic inverter](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs6710/handouts/AppendixB/appendixB.doc3.html) is used to provide the complement of the VLOAD signal. The input to the inverter is VLOAD, and it is powered by the voltage source. The output of the inverter is VLOADN.

D1 and D2 have shared cathodes. Since VLOADN = ~VLOAD, there is always one LED that is on while the other is off:

- If SW1 is closed, the inverter input is high. D1 is on and D2 is off.
- If SW1 is open, R4 pulls the input of the inverter low. D1 is off and D2 is on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2uCy5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't understand though, with the switch open, how does anything get power?

Comment: @Sean: The logic is driven off a separate regulator.

Comment: Any chance you could further explain the circuit for the inverter? I'm still just starting out with circuitry and from what I understand, I could make it with a series of transistors, and/or diodes, but it is possible to make a super simple one with a single transistor. Problem is, that is basically what I had in the first example. 

Could you show what would be the easiest way to make the inverter? Is it an IC or something that I'd have to create?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. Fewer components are better, but if there's something new I don't yet understand, then that means that there's something more I can learn ^_^

Comment: @Sean, there you have it. I don't know if it works, or the resistor values you need, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! One question though, what stops D2 from being always on? It appears that it has one resistor between the anode and the power supply, and one resistor between it and the cathode and the power supply, but nothing inbetween which would stop the current.

Comment: That's the magic of Q1. When Q1 is turns on, it provides a path from VLOADN to ground. From the link, "The output (of the inverter) is discharged to ground, getting close to 0 V but never quite reaching it (it reaches a voltage drop away from 0 V)." So when Q1 is on, D2 will have close to ground at both terminals so it will not be on.

Comment: Huh, that's fascinating! That makes sense though. Thank you so much for all of your help! Now how do I go about calculating the resistor values? What are they all dependent on? I understand R1 as that comes from a simple LED circuit, but the others?

Comment: R4 should be relatively large so that it doesn't drain the power supply unnecessarily. I would calculate R1 based on the current you want through D1 when the SW1 is closed. R3 should be relatively small so that D2 gets about the same current as D1. But it has to be large enough that it doesn't overpower Q1 when Q1 is on. If D1 is too much brighter than D2 you can put a resistor with the  same value as R3 at the D1 anode. This will balance the two. R2 controls the drive strength of Q1. I think it should be relatively low.

Comment: Just don't choose R1 to be so small that you blow your LEDs. Otherwise, you should be able to safely play around with the sizes and see how changing them affects the circuit, and let me know how it goes. I have to say I haven't even touched a BJT in years...

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9GsV7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This curcuit will do it for you, assuming D1 is red and D2 is green. R3 specifies current through LEDs. The trick is that when D2 lights up, R1 makes voltage on D1 less than its forward voltage drop need to light it.

Comment: Hmm but what if there is some other load we want to drive with that switch?

Comment: R4 is the load. It may have any type. But be careful with inductive load such as motor as it may break LED.

Comment: Would something like the coil on a relay harm the LED?

Comment: That's interesting to carefully balance the two lines so that even when the circuit is closed for both, only one would light up. As long as the voltage source is well regulated, there is no danger of damaging the LEDs, unless the switch itself doesn't behave like an ideal open or short. But none of these designs are really safe against that.

Comment: trav1s, unbalanced circuit (too large R1) will have green brighter than red, so there's only task is to tune R1 for aestetic. If you worry about bad regulator you can take more powerful LED to survive maximum voltage.

Comment: Sean, coil may damage LED. To protect use a diode parallel to load with reverse polarity.

Comment: Note, if you take blue led for D1, you will not need R1 at all, as forward voltage for blue one is greater than for green.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is another method that I came up with. When the switch is open, there is no voltage drop across the resistor and the IRF closes. Just make sure the Vgs of the MOSFET is close to 5V.

Or tie the gate of the transistor to the cathode, and expect a 1.5V drop across LED with 0 current flowing through it.